# worker thread keeps waiting at condition_variable even the notify_all is called

Tags: c++, multithreading

I got code like below:

```
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable condition_variable;
bool finish = false;

void test() {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    condition_variable.wait(lock);
    if (finish){
      std::cout << "finish detected" << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  std::thread t(test);
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
  finish = true;
  lock.unlock();
  //sleep(1);
  condition_variable.notify_all();
  std::cout << "notify_all" << std::endl;
  t.join();
}
```

and the code will not terminate when running, the `notify_all` log will print, but the `finish detected` log will not. If I use debug mode, the code will terminate successfully, so I cannot provide a clear clue about the status of the running code, but if I release the `sleep(1)`, the code will works.

So can anyone help what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condition variables have no state, so that when you signal it and there are no waiters the signal is lost. It happens in your code when `condition_variable.notify_all()` executes before `condition_variable.wait(lock);`.

The code doesn't use correct method to wait on the condition variable. The correct method is:

1. Lock the mutex.
2. Check the condition (`finish` here).
3. If the condition is not satisfied, wait on the condition variable. [The condition variable can be woken up spuriously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). Goto 2.

Fix:

```
void test() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    while(!finish)
        condition_variable.wait(lock);
    std::cout << "finish detected" << std::endl;
}
```

There is another overload of [`condition_variable::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) that does the `while` loop for you:

```
void test() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    condition_variable.wait(lock, [&finish]{ return finish; });
    std::cout << "finish detected" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: HI, you code works, but I'm still don't know why my code not working, why do I need to re-check the `finish` when wake up?

Comment: @reavenisadesk Condition variables have no state, so that when you signal it and there are no waiters the signal is lost. You need to recheck the condition after the wakeup because of the spurios wakeups. Read the links I provided, they explain it in detail.

Comment: Noticed you `The condition variable can be woken up spuriously`, thanks very much, I don't know this before.

Comment: @reavenisadesk In your case, I dare to guess that the problem is not caused by spurious wakeup (these are rare). The problem is likely caused by calling `wait` after `notify_all` took place. This is resolved in the answer, since if `notify_all` is called first, `finish` already has been set and `wait` will not be called at all.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica The problem is not caused by spurious wakeups here. But spurious wakeups must be handled regardless.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica, I think you are right, I add logs with timestamps, and the `notify_all` called earlier, I think this is the root case. And in debug mode, `wait` called first (I don't know why)

Comment: @reavenisadesk Added a note for you with the root cause. Note that logging introduces synchronization and changes the observable behaviour.